# Google Chrome range.getClientRects bug in browser or intended behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, multipleselection

I'm playing with Web Selection API and trying to implement multi selection in Google Chrome (something similar to Firefox multi selection with Ctrl button). To achieve this I'm using HTML canvas element together with Selection API and Range API. Here is my code:

```
//Ctrl + A doesn't work yet
that.container.on('mouseup', function (event) {
  var selection = window.getSelection(),
    rects, range;

  //we select nothing, just click on the text
  if (selection.isCollapsed || selection.rangeCount < 1)
    return;

  //highlight selection
  range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  rects = range.getClientRects();

  for (let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    let rect = rects[i];
    canvas.drawRect(rect.left, rect.top,
                        rect.width, rect.height, '#a8d1ff');
  }
});
that.container.on('mousedown', function (event) {
  var range = document.createRange(),
    textRange = range.selectNode(that.container[0]),
    rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.clearRect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height)
});
```

The idea behing this is to allow user select two things in two diffirent regions of web page. It works well when we select text in only one paragraph but it leads to some unintended behavior when we select text between several paragraphs. [Here](http://ilex.imz.re/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=selection_api_problem.webm) is short video clip that shows what is going on.

I'm running Chromium 50.0.2661.102 Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle or something?

Comment: I've found working work around. My solution is to not use block elements in your text at all. Paragraphs can be divided by double <br /> and it works pretty well.